# Trimming path to latest arbitrary folder name

Tags: shell, makefile

I'm writing a makefile where I have access to the path the file is running. `MKFILE_PATH`.

`MKFILE_PATH= $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))`

I want to trim this path, cutting off the end to the last `packages`.

Here are some examples:

- input: `/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo/packages/event-as-promised/packages/node_modules/.bin/ied`
- output: `/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo/packages/event-as-promised`
- imput: `/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo/packages/event-as-promised/node_modules/.bin/ied`
- output: `/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo`

How can I manipulate a path with shell / make?

Answer (score 2):

We can use parameter subsitution to remove the shortest matching part from the right end of the string like this:

```
$ var="/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo/packages/event-as-promised/packages/node_modules/.bin/ied"
$ echo "${var%packages*}"
/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo/packages/event-as-promised/
$ var="/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo/packages/event-as-promised/node_modules/.bin/ied"
$ echo "${var%packages*}"
/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/monorepo/
```

`${var%Pattern}` means remove from `$var` the shortest part of Pattern that matches the back end(from the right) of `$var`.

To remove the longest matching part we can use `${var%%Pattern}`.

More info on parameter substitution can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: Hey thanks! For some reason this works in the terminal, but not in the makefile. Any ideas why?

Comment: In a Make recipe, shell variables are accessed with double dollar signs.  You might need something like `var='$(MAKEVARIABLE)'; echo "$${var%packages*}"`